# How to remove iteams tag from response of google endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have create an API which is returning the  the list of users i want to give the name to that list. by default google endpoint is giving name **"items"** to the list of object.  I want to change this name. Please suggest how can i do this.

```
{
 "items": [
   {
     "id": 1,
   "userTypeID": 1,
    "userCurrentLocationID": 0,
    "updateBy": 1,
   "timeZone": "",
  "state": 0,
  "postcode": "110085",
  "phone": "",
   "officeAddressID": 227,
  "mobile": "9999999",
  "lineManager": "",
  "email": "abc@abc.com",
  "createdBy": "prbhat.ydav@gmail.com",
   "countryID": 1,
   "companyID": 227,
  "city": "delhi"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Pls show the corresponding response Message class.

Answer (score 0):

If you return `List<T>` from an Endpoint, it will always name the list in an `items` field. I believe behind the scenes it's using `CollectionResponse` so that's why, but my memory is rusty. If you want the name to be something else, simply wrap the list in an object with a different field name. Note that Endpoints requires JSON objects to be returned, so you can't return a JSON array with no wrapping.